# Pass char* to const char* in c

Tags: c

I got a problem. I want to use one `CopyString()` function to copy `const char*`s and `char*`s to a buffer. It shouldn't be a problem but for some reason my compiler doesn't do the thing I expect it to do (I use MikroC for PIC pro).

```
 void CopyString(char * dest, const char * src, uint8 maxLength){
    uint8 i;
    for(i=0 ; src[i] && ( i < maxLength ) ; i++){
        dest[i] = src[i];
    };
}   

char test[3]={'2', '0', ' '};
CopyString(buf, test, 3);//gives an error (illigal pointer conversion)
CopyString(buf, (const char *)test, 3); //Doesn't pass the pointer to the array... No idea why not... Do you?

void CopyString2(char * dest, char * src, uint8 maxLength){
    uint8 i;
    for(i=0 ; src[i] && ( i < maxLength ) ; i++){
        dest[i] = src[i];
    };
}   
const char test[3]={'2', '0', ' '};
CopyString2(buf, "20 ", 3);//All ok
CopyString2(buf, test, 3); //gives an error (illigal pointer conversion)
```

Anyone knows how to do this? Currently I use `CopyString2()` and `CopyString()` in one C document which isn't looking nice and it shouldn't be required. Why would pass a `char*` to a `const char*` give problems? The only thing `const char*` does is making sure the data in the char array won't change within the function, right?

Edit:
Here an edit with the 'whole' example code (which should be a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example).
With Keil compiler (which I use to program for ARM mcu's) it compiles just fine (like I would expect) but with MikroC PIC compiler (as far as I can find this is how the compiler is called.) it gives the following error:

> 18 384 Illegal pointer conversion main.c
>   (line 18, message no. 384)
>
> 23 384 Illegal pointer conversion main.c
>   (line 23, message no. 384)

```
void CopyString(char * dest, const char * src, unsigned char maxLength){
    unsigned char i;
    for(i=0 ; src[i] && ( i < maxLength ) ; i++){
        dest[i] = src[i];
    };
}   

void CopyString2(char * dest, char * src, unsigned char maxLength){
    unsigned char i;
    for(i=0 ; src[i] && ( i < maxLength ) ; i++){
        dest[i] = src[i];
    };
}   

void main(){
    char buf[16]={0,};
    char test1[3]={'2', '0', ' '};
    const char test2[3]={'2', '0', ' '};

    CopyString(buf, test1, 3);//gives an error (illigal pointer conversion);
    CopyString(buf, (const char *)test1, 3); //Doesn't pass the pointer to the array

    CopyString2(buf, "20 ", 3);//All ok
    CopyString2(buf, test2, 3); //gives an error (illigal pointer conversion);
}
```

Comment: Post your *actual code*.

Comment: When posting question about build errors, please include the actual errors in the body of the question, complete, in full and *unedited*. Also include any possible informational notes given by the compiler. Preferably copy-paste the build log.

Comment: Your examples are not *complete* (see [mcve]). Also, if you are getting compilation errors, also post *complete* error messages.

Comment: How is `buf`declared ? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise the question is likely downvoted or closed.

Comment: `char buf[100];
  char test[3]={'2', '0', ' '};
  CopyString(buf, test, 3);` compiles fine here.

Comment: Hi, thanks all! I did an edit. @MichaelWalz Yes; here too with Keil compiler but it does not with MikroC PRO PIC compiler which should also be an ANSI c compiler.

Comment: The program you show is a valid C program, but IIRC the Microchip C compiler is not very up to date with standards which can lead to problems. You might need to use [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) to make it work on the different compilers.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg. I'll wait for some more responses and then I'll contact MikroC.

Comment: @Sander your compiler seem to be broken. You have to cope with it (not using const, having 2 versions of the function). Or get another compiler.

Comment: You are passing spaces rather than NULLs at the end of your strings.  Because you are supplying the correct length you should be OK, but its not good practice.

Comment: Try `(const char *)&test[0]` just to be more explicit maybe? Other than that I've come across multiple C compilers made for PICs that are just rubbish in terms of little undocumented things like this.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, you're right!

Comment: @Toby: I already tried that but it did not help unfortunately.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: That's clear language. Thanks! Ok, now I know it's not my fault. I almost thought I did becom insane. :-)
Thanks all!!! 
MichaelWalz; can you place an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think he is talking about Mikroelectronika's MicroC compiler, not Microchip's C compilers. But what you said probably applies to both compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem related to how const variables are implemented for PIC controller. In PIC controllers the RAM and Code are located in different types of memory. RAM is SD-RAM, and code is flash memory.(RAM is accessible through register and ram operations, and code is only automatically decoded, or read through a complicated sequence of assembly operations.) Since the RAM is very small, const values are stored as Return Literal instructions in the Code Memory(To bypass the difficulty of reading Flash memory otherwise), which is larger.

So you can't really do the same operations on both types. It's something you need to learn to live with. I suggest you look at the disassembly of this code to see what's really going on.

Comment: @Toby Although the edaboard thread is about passing a const char* to a function which requires a char*. In this case I can get that the string first needs to be copied to RAM because the function may need the string to be not-constant. But my problem is about passing a char* to a function which accepts a const char*. I don't see a reason why such a function wouldn't accept a char*. Anyhow, thanks for your response!

Comment: @SurDin I believe it's something which always happens in the world of mcu's: constants are stored only in flash. I believe it wouldn't make sense if any compiler would not do so. I also make use of a Keil (arm) compiler which does not make any problem of char*'s passed as a const char* argument although it does still store const char*'s only in flash. Why would a PIC be different? Maybe because it needs a different kind of memory access sequence for both type of memory. Still it doesn't make much of sense to me. But anyhow; thanks for your answer!

Comment: In PIC's there's no command to read from flash what it does when it reads a const from flash it executes a "Call <addr>" command and gets the value in W register.
When it reads a char array, there's a different command for a read indirect. These are very different types of assembly instructions. You need overloaded functions for this type of functionality.
Usually you can read from flash from a RAM mapped address in processors which do this without a problem.

Comment: Ok, Thanks SurDin! That must be it.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before in other compilers a long time ago - note I've never used this compiler before.

The "array is-a pointer" concept of C causes *a lot* of problems with newbies. To prevent that, some compiler writers got very pernickety (it's a word! Look it up!) and required you to pass the address of a character to a `const char *` instead of merely an array.

Can you try `CopyString2(buf, &test[0], 3);`?

Or even `CopyString2(buf, (const char *)&test[0], 3);`?

Comment: Your first suggestion did result in the same error as previous. Your second suggestion does, for some weird reason, not pass the right pointer.